# Lifetime of an array in a header file

Tags: c, arrays, header-files

I want to define an array in a header file, together with the function using it. Not inside the function, but at the top, like a global variable.

Now I am not sure if this will work at all. How long would the array live? Is it like creating a local variable in a loop or will it stay alive since #include "said_header.h" untill the program's end?

Comment: My question is, why do you have an array and a function in a header file at all? A header file should contain types, declarations and macros but not definitions.

Comment: I would like to make my main.c a bit cleaner, for now I have a lot of stuff declared there and it feels kind of cluttered.

Comment: A header file is treated as if it was copied verbatim into the source file. So the answer to your question depends on what's in the header file, and where you include it in the source file. In other words, you need to post some code.

Comment: If you're trying to reduce the amount of clutter in `main.c`, you should split some of the functions into another `.c` file.

Comment: You could declare the function in the header file, then create another .c file and add the array.Compile the .c file with -c switch in gcc.This will create an object file that you will need in order to link your main.c. e.g gcc -c array.c , gcc main.c array.o. Include the header file in both .c files.

Comment: Generally, an object defined outside any function lives for the entire duration of the program.  It doesn't matter whether it was defined via inclusion from a header file or directly in a .c file.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Then, as others already said, *please*, post some code by [edit]ing your question. Don't put additional information in a comment, this is not a forum.

Comment: "I want to define an array in a header file".  No, you really don't.  That's like saying "I want to ignore decades of best practices and make my code unusable".  You want to declare an array in the header file, and then define it (and the function) in a *.c file.  You do not want to have definitions for the array and/or the function in multiple translation units, and the whole point of header files is to make declarations visible in multiple translation units.  Definitions do not belong in header files.  Ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that `#include "headerfile.h"` in C is more or less logically equivalent to opening your text editor and replacing the `#include` line with the entire contents of the included file.

So, header files are best used for *declarations* (which need to be shared between different source files, aka compilation units), while *definitions* are best kept in just one source file.  Note that you can declare an object, and then define it, and indeed doing so when the declaration is in a header file is a good way to allow the compiler to verify that the declaration and the definition match.

so in `headerfile.h` you might put the declaration of your array:

```
extern char array[100];
```

and in **one** of your source files you might define your array:

```
#include "headerfile.h"
char array[100];
```

and in other source files you can just reference the global array:

```
#include "headerfile.h"

strncpy(array, "some string", sizeof(array) - 1);
```